# Finding company name from a ticker in Bloomberg

Tags: bloomberg

I have a list of tickers, but when I use https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/symbolsearch to find the company name, it shows that tickers are incorrect.

This is the code:

```
def check_ticker(soup, ticker_c):
    tables = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "dual_border_data_table"})
    company_name = ""
    if len(tables) > 0:
        bm_table = tables[0]
        rows = bm_table.findAll("tr")
        row = rows[1]
        cells = row.findAll("td")
        if cells[0].get_text() == ticker_c:
            cn = cells[1].get_text()
            company_name = cn
        else:
            company_name = ""
    else:
        b = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ticker_nomatches"})
        if len(b) > 0:
            company_name = ""
    return company_name
```

This is the list for which it is not getting any matches:

```
ESS PW
KKD US
QVCA US
HAR US
LXK US
WWAV US
HEN3 GR
036220 KS
CIG PW
068420 KS
6767 JP
OVTI US
SCTY US
CSC US
STRZA US
ISG LN
```

Are there any APIs to do this?

Comment: you could try openfigi.com which is a system run by Bloomberg for symbol  lookups.  It also has a REST api.

Comment: Some of those tickers are for companies that have been acquired or delisted...

Comment: @assylias is correct, those tickers are for companies that have been acquired so will not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out this bloomberg API:

One can use `=BDP("ticker","field")` to download the company names.

For example, ESS PW Equity

And the field for company name is "NAME"

This gives `:=BDP("ESS PW Equity","Name")` company name.