# Retrieving Company Name from Web Search using Ticker

Tags: r, finance, ticker

I have a list of 3000+ tickers for which I would like to get their respective company names. I couldn't find these names using the Bloomberg database.

I manually checked on Google for few of them and found that the first web page in google search that gives the company's name when I enter the US-based tickers is that of Bloomberg. For example, when I searched for "0000284D US Equity", the first page is https://www.bloomberg.com/profile/company/0000284D:US. For non-US based tickers such as "010520 KS Equity", the first page that shows the company's name could be something else.

I checked posts like this one - [Finding company name from a ticker in Bloomberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907977/finding-company-name-from-a-ticker-in-bloomberg) - but couldn't find the relevant solution.

Is there any R package that can help in fetching the company name from web search using the ticker? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You could pull all tickers with companies’ name from NASDAQ etc as CSV and merge that with your data frame?

Comment: @TomHoel - Thanks a lot! I retrieved the list of 55k firms whose data is available on Bloomberg and couldn't match 3k tickers out of 9k tickers in my data with that list. Will try your suggestion as well. I think some firms may have got merged or closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a package in R but could find a package in python that can help. We can pass the tickers in a list and then print their long names as below.

```
pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yfin
x = yfin.Ticker("AAPL")
print(x.info['longName'])
```